# Blender to unity cube isn't showing all sides

Tags: unity

I have a blender model in the picture below
[image]

But when I import it to unity it is as shown below

[image]

If we zoom in a bit

[image]

It seems the cubes are only showing 2 sides of itself and not the full cube?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some of your (plank) faces have their normals flipped.
You can check it in Blender using either the *Face orientation* or the *Normals* options from the Viewport Overlay.

[image]

Comment: Yep that worked, ty.